# Error : date/time field value out of range: "30/12/2014 23:58:04" postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to import csv file into postgresql data base

I already tried `set datestyle = mdy`

```
 \copy "Recon".snapdeal_sales (REFERENCES , ORDER_CODE ,SUB_ORDER_CODE ,    
  PRODUCT_NAME , ORDER_VERIFIED_DATE , ORDER_CREATED_DATE, AWBNO ,
  SHIPPING_PROVIDER , SHIPPING_CITY , SHIPPING_METHOD , INVOICE_NUMBER ,    
  INVOICE_DATE , IMEI_SERIAL , STATUS , MANIFEST_BY_DATE , SHIPPED_ON ,
  DELIVERED_ON , RETURN_INITIATED_ON , RETURN_DELIVERED_ON , SKU_CODE ,   
  PACKAGE_ID ,PRODUCT_CATEGORY, ATTRIBUTES , IMAGE_URL , PDP_URL , FREEBIES 
  ,TRACKING_URL , ITEM_ID , MANIFEST_CODE , PROMISED_SHIP_DATE , 
  NON_SERVICABLE_FROM , HOLD_DATE , HOLD_REASON , MRP 
  ,EXPECTED_DELIVERY_DATE ,TAX_PERCENTAGE , CREATED ,RPI_DATE 
  ,RPI_ISSUE_CATEGORY , RPR_DATE) FROM 'C:\Users\YAM\Documents\SALES.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: If "30" represents the month, then "out of range" makes sense. What other values for datestyle did you try?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First, run this query.

```
  SET datestyle = dmy;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Last night when i change the date style at that time query did not run but today morning , I run this query then it works . what do you think what happen ?

Comment: `SET datestyle` is effective for either the current session or the current transaction. If you restart PostgreSQL or restart your computer, PostgreSQL will go back to using the value that's set in postgresql.conf.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall'  yes you are right , but it is not working for me which csv file i want to upload .

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was getting this error :
psycopg2.errors.DatetimeFieldOverflow: date/time field value out of range 23-09-2021

soln : check what format the date is present in your db and change the date format in your query accordingly.

In my case it was in a format : yyyy-mm-dd, I was query with dd-mm-yyyy that caused the error, just simply change this.

Ex : http://localhost:port/tweets?date=2021-09-23

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).