# How do I extract the month from the Date column in SQL-postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-science, data-analysis

I am trying to extract the month from the the Order_date column by using postgres SQL , and the format is required to come in the name of the month format ;for example, December.

When I applied the extract function , It gave me an error message saying that the date setting has to be changed.

Please advise how to extract the month from the mentioned column ?

The data has been enclosed

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM order_date::date)
FROm think_sales;
```

The error message :

> [22008] ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "25/06/2021" Hint: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.

Data :

[image]

Comment: please don't post images of data see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to define your date format using the to_date function:

```
select to_char(to_date('25/06/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'Month');
```

Output: `June`

In your case, you would use:

```
select to_char(to_date(order_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'Month');
```

Comment: It successfully works ! Thanks @Isolated

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP '25/06/2021');

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date-functions/postgresql-extract/

Answer (score 0):

set date format to dmy (day - month - year )

```
SET datestyle = dmy;
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29383758/17057006)